# Nginx and 404 on try_files with .html

Tags: php, html, nginx, url-rewriting

Given this SEF URL `/attrazioni/madame-tussauds-londra.html`
I need to call the real URL which is `/index.php?q=/attrazioni/madame-tussauds-londra.html`

I have this directive but works fine only for the SEF URL without the extension, in that case `/attrazioni/madame-tussauds-londra/`

```
location {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$request_uri;
}
```

What I'm wrong? Why with the URLs with the trailing `.html` doesn't work and return a 404 page?

Answer (score 0):

Not a real issue. After `try_files` my configuration did include this:

```
location ~* \.(html|htm|txt)$ {
    add_header Cache-Control "public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate";
    access_log off;
    expires 1d;
    break;
}
```